# Need sync .conf file manually in openstack multi-node environment?

Tags: openstack

I have an openstack multi-node environment( one controller, one compute, one network). The question is if I changed one of .conf file like nove.conf in controller node, do I need manually sync it to other  two nodes (network and compute) or openstack will automatically sync it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to sync. Just restart corresponding services in corresponding nodes. Thats it. The services will read it.
Also the conf in different nodes are different even if the conf name is same.